# Play framework how do sessions and cookies work?

Tags: java, scala, authentication, cookies, playframework-2.0

How does play validate a cookie?

- I noticed that after I restarted the server I was still logged in even though I
  don't presist any session data in the database.
- I also noticed
  that I could set the date on the server to be larger that the exipry
  date of the cookie and still I was logged in.
- I logged out
  (saved the cookie to a text file) and the browser lost the cookie. Then I
  recreated the cookie from the text file and I was logged in again.

The cookie looks like this:

PLAY_SESSION=e6443c88da7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-userid%3A1

```
// My logout code
def logout() = Action {
  Ok("").withNewSession
}
```

---

[From the documentation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaSessionFlash)
**Discarding the whole session**
There is special operation that discards the whole session:

```
Ok("Bye").withNewSession
```

Answer (score 11):

You didn't specify how do you authenticate users, so I just guess, that you;re using simple sample which is... simple.

It uses user's id to identify the user, and check if signed session cookie wasn't manipulated, therefore if you'll recreate the cookie with proper signature it will be valid still.

You should create some area for session's keys on the server side ie. in DB or in memory cache (Which will be faster than DB). Its key should be randomly generated (and preferebly quite long) for each successful login action, and should also contain data for identifying user, expiration date etc. Next you should put this random `sess_key` to the Play's session instead email address of logged user or id of his row in DB, and after logout and/or expiration date it should be removed. In such case even if you'll loose the cookie after logout it will be impossible to login properly with non-esixting `sess_key`.

AFAIR standard memory cache will be purged at every restart of the application, to make sure that all `sess_keys` from DB will be removed as well you can use [Global object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) and truncate the table in `onStart(...)` method.

Comment: Is it fair at this point to simply stay out of Play's session eco-system (as far as authentication goes)?  I'm thinking of using redis for a semi-durable cache to manage sesh id's and seperately use Play's sessions for storing public session data.  This sound like a good plan?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer reading [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaSessionFlash) more carefully and combining different parts.

> There is no technical timeout for the Session. It expires when the
>   user closes the web browser. If you need a functional timeout for a
>   specific application, just store a timestamp into the user Session and
>   use it however your application needs (e.g. for a maximum session
>   duration, maximum inactivity duration, etc.).

---

> It’s important to understand that Session and Flash data are not
>   stored by the server but are added to each subsequent HTTP request,
>   using the cookie mechanism. This means that the data size is very
>   limited (up to 4 KB) and that you can only store string values.

---

So that was what i feared that if the cookie get lost anyone can log in to the server for all future.

What I have to do to secure this is to add a self-made timestamp authorization (save a timestamp in the cookie and validate sever side)

Comment: "if the cookie get lost anyone can log in to the server for all future", what does that even mean? If there's no cookie, there's no access, it's all client side, Play just ensures the (signed) cookie itself hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: Don't think of lost as void but as gone astray.

Comment: In the future, Please link to the relevant docs, to allow readers of your answers to investigate further.