# Play 2.3 cookie remains usable after expiration

Tags: scala, security, playframework, session-cookies

I have a Play 2.3.7 application which I have configured the `session.maxAge` value. Authentication is done via a token in the session. If I log in, allow the `maxAge` duration to pass, and attempt to call an endpoint, I get a 401 as expected. However, if I copy the cookie from the browser while it is still valid, let it expire, and then manually add the cookie back to the browser's cookies, it appears that the cookie works again.

My questions are:

1. Are the cookie expirations only enforced on the browser?
2. If so, is it left to the developer to permanently expire cookies
   if desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answers**

1. Yes
2. Yes

**In details**

It looks like you did just simple authentification, so you store all session information in the cookies. Play only ensure that cookie is correctly signed. That's all. So if you will copy and past the same cookie then yes - it will work, and yes - it will work forever (until you change the secret key on the server side)

**Even more**

Please read @biesior answer to this question
[Play framework how do sessions and cookies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627802/play-framework-how-do-sessions-and-cookies-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Great thanks! So what the heck is the point of the session max age then, if it remains usable?

Comment: Uhm, historically there was no this setting in the play 2.0, but later (2.3, I suppose) it has been added to the Play on "users requests". It looks like it has sense in an MVP scenario when app need to be ready in a short time for a small number of "selected users".  Then you could use this simple pseudo timeout, and later add full support for tokens and timeouts.

Comment: Sounds like a dangerous honeypot. Thanks for the clarification!